# Adding a simple custom legend to a barplot in ggplot2 and having negative bars below the x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to create a simple bar plot plotting temperatures against time in ggplot2 but I am running into trouble creating a legend and having the negative valued bars actually go below the x axis.

Here is my data:

```
DSW_op_mean <- c(-3.6, -0.1,  2.2,  4.2,  5.4,  6.2,  5.4,  4.4,  2.4,  1.2)

date <- c("06/11", "06/12", "06/13", "06/14", "06/15", "06/16", "06/17", "06/18", "06/19", "06/20")

DSW.data  <- cbind(DSW_op_mean, date)
DSW.data <- as.data.frame(DSW.data)

meanAvgHighDSW <- 99.1
```

I can plot this fine in base R as shown with this image:

[image: Base R plot]

When I attempt to plot this in ggplot, I cannot get the blue bars to go negative or a legend to show up. I've tried a few different things for the legend, but none have worked so I left that part out in the ggplot code:

```
ggplot(data = DSW.data, aes(x= date, y = DSW_op_mean, fill= DSW_op_mean)) + 
  geom_bar(colour= "black", fill= ifelse(DSW_op_mean>0,"red","blue"), stat= "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label= paste(DSW_op_mean, "°F"), vjust=-.5)) + xlab("Date")+ ylab("Avg High Temp Departure °F")+
 ggtitle("10 Day Desert SW High Temp Forecast")
```

Here is the image that displays:

[image: ggplot bar chart version]

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You are being tripped up at least in part by this:

```
DSW.data  <- cbind(DSW_op_mean, date)
DSW.data <- as.data.frame(DSW.data)
```

The `cbind`/`as.data.frame` pattern for building data frames is a very, very common mistake. `cbind` is coercing your numeric column to character, and then `as.data.frame` converts it all to factors.

There is a function specifically designed for creating data frames. It's called.....`data.frame()`!

```
DSW.data  <- data.frame(DSW_op_mean = DSW_op_mean, date = date)
```

You plot works for me in this case (with a warning) although I'm not sure you get the legend you want. To fix the legend, try this:

```
DSW.data$col <- ifelse(DSW.data$DSW_op_mean > 0,'Pos','Neg')

ggplot(data = DSW.data, aes(x= date, y = DSW_op_mean, fill= col)) + 
    geom_bar(colour= "black", stat= "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(label= paste(DSW_op_mean, "°F"), vjust=-.5)) + 
    xlab("Date")+ 
    ylab("Avg High Temp Departure °F")+
    ggtitle("10 Day Desert SW High Temp Forecast")
```

Comment: Pass `position = "identity"` to `geom_bar`. They probably also want `scale_fill_manual(values = c("Neg" = "blue", "Pos" = "red"), guide = "none")`.

Comment: Thank you, both of you. I appreciate the comments on the data.frame function, that is very helpful. The position= "identity" did the trick, thanks. Still trying to figure out the legend.

Comment: @user3720887 Well, if you actually want a legend, don't suppress is: `scale_fill_manual(values = c("Neg" = "blue", "Pos" = "red")`. You should study some ggplot2 tutorials.